# Regex: How to combine a condition to match any non-white-space character individually while ignoring content inside a bracket pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to convert all non-white-space characters from a string into some other character (like `_`). I am using `\S` to select each non-white-space character and substituting it with another character reasonably well.

```
import re
mystring = "Explore in further detail"
print(re.sub('\S', '_', mystring))
```

returns

```
_______ __ _______ ______
```

However, I also want to skip portions of the string that match a bracketed pattern such as `%{object}`.

With

```
([^[\}]+)(?=$|\%\{)
```

I can match anything outside of the brackets, but this doesn't help me substitute each non-white space character individually. How can I combine the two?

In summary I want a regular expression that can turn a string like

```
Explore %{object} in further detail
```

and turn it into something like.

```
_______ %{object} __ _______ ______
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that a specific kind of whitespace character won't show up in your data to be replaced you can do it in three operations, replace the `%{object}` with this un-used token, then convert all remaining characters to whitespaces, then replace your token white-space character with the original `%{object}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture `%{object}` using a negated character class in group 1 using `(%{[^{}]*})`

In the callback, if group 1 exists return it unmodified. Else return the underscore.

```
import re

mystring = "Explore %{object} in further detail"
print(re.sub(r'(%{[^{}]*})|\S', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '_', mystring))
```

Output

```
_______ %{object} __ _______ ______
```

---

Using the pattern that you suggested with the negated character class and the lookahead, you can match all except curly braces until you either get to the end of the string or the `%{object}` part.

As that would also match spaces, in the callback you can get the match from the `.group()` and replace all the non whitespace chars with an extra call to `re.sub`

```
[^[{}]+(?=$|%{[^{}]*})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/549jkp/1)

```
import re

mystring = "Explore %{object} in further detail"
print(re.sub(r'[^[{}]+(?=$|%{[^{}]*})', lambda x: re.sub(r"\S", '_', x.group()), mystring))
```

Output

```
_______ %{object} __ _______ ______
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Ultimately this answer uses a two step process. Out of curiosity, and for those readers who are not programming in python, is there a pure regex syntax that can achieve the same effect in a single expression?

Comment: There are other options, if for example the string can not contain `{` `}` or `%` chars, you might use the PyPi module and the `\G` anchor. See https://regex101.com/r/97YvJC/1 and [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##PY5PC4JAEMXv@ykGQfyDdOkmRKfo0EdwNbTG2jB3mR3B2Pazm2I4p5k3j/d@5sNP3e@nSb2NJgbCB45CmJoZqYcDUBAf89AVlfNl6r/ynEibyktRSet8WAZC2NkVnEbTaUIInW5eeGMPqod2IH4iwR25Vt322hZGy9sxJxHaoeOldKHY2aGJ/yAZRNcoA5sIoVpYfbmAeQypniFepWSafg)

Comment: Or using the PyPi regex module using skip fail https://regex101.com/r/mlE07U/1 See this [Python example](https://tio.run/##PY5PC4JAEMXv@ykGQdwV6dIt6FgQXQKP/UNryg3bXWZHMMzPvimGc5r3fsN74z5cWbMMQb@dJQbCJ7ZCuIIZycAaKIq746Xrz2kv03y/OyiZbtX3lEdC@IFHm9bVlhDizpYvvHEP2sCjIa6Q4I5c6HpG88LoeRZDEqFvah7rxv6Fb0r5fyGD5Jpk4JUQ@gHT3UrAMI60YZCTpUL4AQ)

Answer (score -1):

I would solve this as two problems instead of 1 regex.

1. Remove all '~'.
2. Find the "${objects}" you want to keep.
3. replace them with '~'.
4. Replace all [^\s~] as '_'.
5. Replace the ['~'] with "${object}"

Simpler than trying to do one massive regex.